# Home-automation standard for custom devices

Tags: home-automation

I'm willing to build my own home-automation system (at least partially). I haven't chosen the protocol yet.
My goal is to make home-automation devices that would be compatible with controllers/software and other devices on the market.

For example, I could create a device with an action named Action1 and I could trigger this action with a standard software.

This way I could buy some devices and build special ones for particular problems.

So is there a standard for house automation related to a particular protocol or not, where devices can be controlled by a compliant software and where devices can communicate their capabilities ?

For those who knows what I am looking for is something like GigE-Vision but for home-automation.

[Edit] As I understand there is no high level protocol widely adopted (i.e : to switch a lightbulb). OpenHab simplifies the dilemma on what will be used (z-wave, insteon, knx, ... because it allows to mix existing "standards".

What is left for me is to decide which technology is the most convenient to use depending on multiple factors like physical chips availability, difficulty to configure them, their price, need or possibility of external microcontroller, etc

Thank you for your valuable inputs.

Comment: Plenty of them, which are "devices that would be compatible with controllers/software and other devices on the market" ?

Comment: "The problem with standards is that there are so many of them"  Unfortunately, at least at the present time this question falls in the category of "Primarily Opinion Based" as there are too many possibilities, and no conclusive, uncontroversial reasons that select a single answer.

Comment: I see DALI fairly often on commercial sites. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Addressable_Lighting_Interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is there a standard for house automation related to a particular protocol or not, where devices can be controlled by a compliant software and where devices can communicate their capabilities ?

No. There are *many* "standards".

[image]

The [OpenHAB](http://openhab.org) open-source project (as in open-habitat) has done a huge amount of work on this with protocols hacked for many commercially available systems. They have an OpenHAB application to run on Linux (Raspberry Pi is suitable platform) and Android (at least) app to control the system. Using their platform you can integrate devices from all the vendors they support.

Comment: Thank you for your reply it helped me a lot. OpenHab seems really great and simplifies my problem a lot since the protocol I'll use will be a less crucial decision in terms of compatibility. I just need to chose the most convenient technology for ease of development and costs.